# Simple MAAS setup in Ubuntu 13.04 and Virtual Box

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox, juju, maas

Main OS : Ubuntu 13.04.

MAAS HOST : installed in virtualbox using   [MAAS Doucmentation](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/quantal/install.html#installing-maas-from-ubuntu-server-boot-media) .

I created another virtual machine connected with same network as MAAS HOST. 
It's booted successfully using PXE after all process.

I am getting `FATAL : ERROR inserting ipmi_si ( no such device )`

And also that node is asking for username and password:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think the question is off-topic, because it involves mostly VirtualBox and is not specific to Ubuntu distribution. However, if I'm wrong, you have to provide information about step where error happens.

Comment: @Danatela you *are* wrong, MAAS is an Ubuntu Project, the rest of your comment applies :-)

Comment: attahced screenshot 
now you can see better 
@Danatela

Answer (score 1):

There is no username and password by default.  Either use juju (preferred) or if you are starting nodes via the MAAS ui then you need to make sure you add your public SSH key to your user preferences.

You can ignore the ipmi error.